# Pass either a regex or string into a Perl subroutine

Tags: perl

I would like to write a Perl subroutine that takes either a string value or a regex value as a parameter and do different things depending on the result. For the sake of this question it simply returns `"regex"` if it is a regex value and `"string"` if it is not a regex:

```
sub value_string_or_regex {
    my ($value) = @_;
    my $result = '';
    # magic here
    return $result;
}
```

So the following code would print out "`string`":

```
print(value_string_or_regex("hello world") . "\n");
```

And the following code would print out "`regex`":

```
print(value_string_or_regex(qr/^.*world$/) . "\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend against that since that which `"hello\s+world"` returns is as much of a regex pattern as that which `qr/hello\s+world/` returns.

That said, you can use builtin [`re::is_regexp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re) to check if a scalar contains a regex pattern compiled by `qr`.